# Code folding and newlines in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, formatting, folding

Like many people, I like to put newlines between my member functions, like so:

```
void foo() {
    // ...
}

void bar() {
    // ...
}
```

The problem is, with code folding, it looks like this:

```
void foo()

void bar()
```

There is an extra newline in there. I can only see half the functions I could otherwise see. Is there a way (or a plugin) that makes Eclipse fold one empty new line with the rest of the function?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell in Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Folding there is no way to specify custom folding beyond the checkboxes provided there. I am unsure about any sort of plugin though so maybe someone else knows about those, but that functionality does not appear to be built into eclipse